# How do I assign file extensions a particular parser using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Suppose I wanted to have all files named ".myexcellentpage" to be parsed with PHP, or with Perl, or as HTML, or what have you. What do I have to do in htaccess to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .mybogusextension    
AddHandler cgi-script .myotherextension
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, the following [`AddType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) should work:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .myexcellentpage
```

(You can specify php4 or php5 explicitly if desired.)

For other things, like Perl CGI, the [`AddHandler`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) directive can be used to specify the handler.